# Automatically moving forked processes in a different cgroupv2

Tags: debian, systemd, apache-httpd, cgroups

I've been using `apache2-mpm-itk` with `cgrulesengd` in cgroupv1 to automatically classify the child processes that `apache2-mpm-itk` spawns when servicing web requests for different vhosts for about 3 years, and it's been working great, when a vhost starts using up too much CPU/RAM, oom killer takes care of that specific vhost and leaves the others alone.

I'm now preparing a new Debian 11 server, and I'm finding out that I need to use cgroup v2 now. So I'm trying to bring my resource control solution to the new world.

When I create my e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/user-UID.slice.d/override.conf` with the resource controls for that user, they don't apply to the forked processes, as `cgrulesengd` used to be able to do, as I am confirming with `systemd-cgls`. Instead, the parent and all its children all still belong to the same apache2.service slice.

Is there a way to automatically classify child processes of a process in a different cgroup than the spawning process with systemd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted the question on the `systemd-devel` mailing list:

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2022-January/047257.html

Here is Benjamin Berg's response:

https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2022-January/047260.html

Very helpful answer by Benjamin. Here is two excerpts:

```
systemd will not help you with managing the cgroup sub-hierarchy
underneath the daemon. I suppose the most generic solution would be
something like cgrulesengd for cgroup v2. No idea if something like
that exists.
```

And:

```
Managing the cgroup hierarchy is quite simple in principle (mkdir and
then a write to cgroup.procs). Or, even better by using
CLONE_INTO_CGROUP when creating the processes. It is not that hard to
write small daemon that does this.
```

**EDIT**:

It appears cgconfigparser and cgrulesengd have been updated to support cgroupv2.

They have to be built from source at the time of this writing.

The package can be downloaded from there:

https://github.com/libcgroup/libcgroup/releases/tag/v2.0

Then follow the steps, e.g.:

```
./configure
make
```

The controller parameters names in cgconfig.conf might be different, make sure you use the cgroupv2 ones in the new world.